# phonegap in android multiple pages

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova

I am a new user in phonegap in android. I am trying to create a project with multiple pages within one html file but it is not working.
The code i have used is shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script> 
<body> 

<!-- Start of first page --> 
<div data-role="page" id="foo"> 

    <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1>Foo</h1> 
    </div><!-- /header --> 

    <div data-role="content">   
        <h2>Foo</h2> 
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#baz" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">baz</a> as a dialog.</p> 
    </div><!-- /content --> 

    <div data-role="footer"> 
        <h4>Page Footer</h4> 
    </div><!-- /footer --> 
</div><!-- /page --> 


<!-- Start of second page --> 
<div data-role="page" id="bar"> 

    <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1>Bar</h1> 
    </div><!-- /header --> 

    <div data-role="content">   
        <h2>Bar</h2> 
        <p>I'm the bar page.</p>        
        <p><a href="#foo" data-direction="reverse">Back to foo</a></p>  
    </div><!-- /content --> 

    <div data-role="footer"> 
        <h4>Page Footer</h4> 
    </div><!-- /footer --> 
</div><!-- /page --> 


<!-- Start of second page --> 
<div data-role="page" id="baz"> 

    <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1>Baz</h1> 
    </div><!-- /header --> 

    <div data-role="content">   
        <h2>Baz</h2> 
        <p>I'm the baz page, viewed as a dialog.</p>        
        <p><a href="#foo" data-rel="back">Back to foo</a></p>   
    </div><!-- /content --> 

    <div data-role="footer"> 
        <h4>Page Footer</h4> 
    </div><!-- /footer --> 
</div><!-- /page --> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Kindly look into this and i appreciate any help that would be available in this regard.

Comment: "It is not working" is a bit vague, what problems are you having. I'm also assuming jQuery Mobile, although you didn't say so. It would also be good to see the whole document so we can spot any issues.

Comment: Hi,                                                                       I am using this code for creating multiple pages by using one HTML file.Bt my output is showing both pages in one window only..pleasse help me in this...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create for each page a div that has a data-role type = page with name unique id

Also, all pages must be stored with the same html file call

```
<a href="#page_id">bar</a>



    <div data-role="page" id="foo" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="content">   
    <h2>Foo</h2> 
    <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
    <p>View internal page called <a href="#foo2">bar</a></p> 
    <p>View internal page called <a href="#foo2" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">baz</a> as a dialog.</p> 
</div><!-- /content --> 

<div data-role="footer"> 
    <h4>Page Footer</h4> 
</div>



<div data-role="page" id="foo2" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="content">   
    <h2>Foo2</h2> 

</div><!-- /content --> 

<div data-role="footer"> 
    <h4>Page Footer</h4> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

McDowell is right, you are missing the `</head>` tag

Also, make sure your .js and .css sources are saved locally and the path to them is relative, not absolute.

Rewrite as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
```

And don't forget the PhoneGap/Cordova .js!

Answer (score 0):

Each page needs to be enclosed in a div with data-role='page'. For multiple pages you should include an id for each page as well.

Eg.

```
<div data-role='page' id='page-foo'>
  <div data-role="content">   
    <h2>Foo</h2> 
    <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
    <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
    <p>View internal page called <a href="#baz" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">baz</a> as a dialog.</p> 
  </div><!-- /content --> 

  <div data-role="footer"> 
    <h4>Page Footer</h4> 
  </div><!-- /footer --> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in the fiddle. Also your page layout and jquery mobile page layout also seems correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/Lbe6P/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed the `</head>`.

After adding it, your code works fine.